# my application force stop after i build even have no any errors, Build Successful but after that, my app crashed

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I running my react native application with `react-native run-android`. nothing wrong here, i already got message BUILD SUCCESSFUL. but after that, my application failed open and instantly force stop. and when i try to reopen app, it's keeps failed to open.

i've tried to see logcat by running on Android Studio, and so i can see logcat why it's happen in my project.

and this is the logcat after my app crashed

```
 --------- beginning of crash
2019-04-04 14:27:12.120 9507-9507/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.timahfrontend, PID: 9507
    java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method com_google_firebase_components_ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1_lambda$new$0(Lcom/google/firebase/components/ComponentRuntime;Lcom/google/firebase/components/Component;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Lcom/google/firebase/components/ComponentRuntime; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime' appears in /data/app/com.timahfrontend-1/base.apk)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime$$Lambda$1.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0)
        at com.google.firebase.components.Lazy.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:53)
        at com.google.firebase.components.AbstractComponentContainer.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:27)
        at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRuntime.get(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:36)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.<init>(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:554)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:365)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:332)
        at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:316)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:53)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1759)
        at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1734)
        at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.1.0:47)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:6420)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:6012)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:5951)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap3(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1710)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6776)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1518)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1408)
```

i expect the application running properly, how to solve this. in my case its look like the problem is from firebase. but i don't know how to solve it. but now the actual process is i running `react-native run-android` then build successful, but with instantly my app stop, and even i try to open again. its keeps stopping

Comment: Did you install it properly in your gradle files?

Comment: yeah , i just following firebase installation instruction in docs

Comment: @DavidHellsing do you have suggestion?